# Change default domain port on CentOS with apache and Docker

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, docker

Sorry for the messy title but not very experienced at those stuff.
Here is my case:

I have **apache2** server on **CentOS**. I installed docker as well on it. Currently my domains are opening as:
**some-domain.com** // this points to the default port from the apache which is **80** which is how it should work for most of the cases.

But currently I have a new domain that will run only on the Docker part which is

**second-domain.com** // this domain opens as well on port **80** but I would like it to run on port **8000** which is the one I am using from docker.

When I open it as **second-domain.com:8000** it works as expected but i want it to open the same way without using **:8000**.

Hope I explained my case, just not sure how to proceed, because I don't want to remove the apache2 from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that all i needed to do is use proxy pass and it did the job, here is the material that helped me.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

I am on CentOS so  just literally had all modules installed by default and only needed to add.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```